# Rails 5 deprecation warning for tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, deprecation-warning

I'm trying to update from rails 4.2.6 to rails 5.0.0.1 but get the following warning when running my tests:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionController::TestCase HTTP request methods
>   will accept only keyword arguments in future Rails versions.
>
> Examples:
>
> get :show, params: { id: 1 }, session: { user_id: 1 } process :update,
>   method: :post, params: { id: 1 }  (called from block in
>    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/my_app/test/controllers/tractions_controller_test.rb:25)

I've been making the appropriate changes to accommodate for this change. However for the integration test line below, I don't know how to change it properly:

```
delete api_sessions_path, { api_session: { org_id: nil } }, { "HTTP_API_TOKEN": "token", "HTTP_USER_EMAIL": @user.email }
```

So the test passes but with the deprecation warning. If I change it to the two options below the test fails with a syntax error. How to properly adjust the line?

```
delete api_sessions_path, params: { api_session: { org_id: nil } }, { "HTTP_API_TOKEN": "token", "HTTP_USER_EMAIL": @user.email }
delete api_sessions_path, params: { { api_session: { org_id: nil } }, { "HTTP_API_TOKEN": "token", "HTTP_USER_EMAIL": @user.email } }
```

**Update**: I've also tried using `session` with the options below but that produces the error `ArgumentError: unknown keyword: session`.

```
delete api_sessions_path, session: { api_session: { org_id: nil } }, params: { "HTTP_API_TOKEN": "token", "HTTP_USER_EMAIL": @user.email }
delete api_sessions_path, params: { api_session: { org_id: nil } }, session: { "HTTP_API_TOKEN": "token", "HTTP_USER_EMAIL": @user.email }
delete api_sessions_path, params: { "HTTP_API_TOKEN": "token", "HTTP_USER_EMAIL": @user.email }, session: { api_session: { org_id: nil } }
delete api_sessions_path, session: { api_session: { org_id: nil } }, { "HTTP_API_TOKEN": "token", "HTTP_USER_EMAIL": @user.email }
```

Comment: Note: I'm guessing. The edge-rails seems to indicate you may need to use more hash-keys than just params eg looking at `get` here: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase/Behavior.html#method-i-delete it shows that there's also `session` and a few others. perhaps the HTTP tokens need to be using `session` instead of `params`?

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it (see update to post) but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. The `headers` tag had to be added:

```
delete api_sessions_path, params: { api_session: { org_id: nil } }, headers: { "HTTP_API_TOKEN": "token", "HTTP_USER_EMAIL": @user.email }
```